# CSS transitions, different durations with the same property?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I know you can set different durations for different properties with CSS transitions. But is it possible to set different durations for the *same* property?

Example: I want a box to grow/shrink in width to *length A **quickly*** when hovered/mouse exits, but grow/shrink in width to *length B **slowly*** when a button is pressed, using a different class.

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/VDyPG/7/

At the moment, the box only grows quickly when hovered, it shrinks back slowly when the mouse exits. Of course this is expected, as the `.box` class has the slow duration speed applied, but is there a way around this? I have worked out a hacky way of doing it with `setTimeout` and an extra "fast" class, but it would be lovely if there was a more elegant way.

**Note:** I'm aware this can be done easily with jQuery. I'm really looking for it to work with CSS however, as the actual problem I'm facing outside of this isolated example is with 3D transforms. Kept it simple for the example. :)

**CSS:**

```
.box {
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; 
}

.lengthA
{   
   width: 300px; 
   -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s; /* Can this be used when class removed? */
}

.lengthB {
     width: 500px;    
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.box').on('mouseenter', function() {

    $(this).addClass('lengthA');            

})

$('.box').on('mouseleave', function() {

    $(this).removeClass('lengthA');            

})    

$('.makeBig').on('click', function() {

    $('.box').toggleClass('lengthB');            

})
```

​**HTML:**

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<button class="makeBig">Grow!</button>
​
```

Comment: I came up with solution based on using 'width' and 'min-width'. And it works. But it takes as back to solution with set of transitions for one class. Is it helpful?

Comment: Hmm that certainly is creative, unfortunately it doesn't really help because in reality my problem is with 3D Transforms, I was just using width as a simple example, didn't want to complicate the question too much. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can by using a variant of this technique: http://css-tricks.com/different-transitions-for-hover-on-hover-off/ . I'm on my iPad right now, so won't those out an example, but the gist of it is that you set a different transition on the hover pseudo selector.

If you want to use jquery, then you can bind to the transitioned event to find out when the previous transition as finished, it's worth noting that the naming isn't consistent -

You'll want to use something like:

```
$("div").bind("webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionEnd transitionend", function(){
  //code
});
```

As it seems that Firefox uses transitionend, rather than the correct transitionEnd.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if this will work, as it always goes back to the original transition-duration when the hover state isn't active. Besides, I have to use jQuery event handlers while adding classes in the actual project, this is an isolated example.

Comment: If you are using jquery already, add class. Change transition properties, remove class, put transitions back. You can bind to the transitionEnd events.

Comment: Ah, transitionEnd event, that's the smart solution! Didn't realise there was such a thing. Thankyou! I had the same idea but was using `setTimeout`, which was too ugly for my liking.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's such a useful event, didn't even know about it!

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<button class="makeBig">Grow!</button>

<style type="text/css">
    .box {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        margin: 10px;
        background: red;
        -webkit-transition: width 250ms ease;
    }
    .box:hover {
        width: 500px;
    }
    .box.slow {
        width: 500px;
        -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
    }
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".makeBig").on("click", function() {
        $('.box').addClass("slow");
    })
</script>
```